# Mercurial Web Server

Tags: visualsvn-server, mercurial

Is there a Mercurial equivalent to VisualSVN Server? I want to setup an http web server for a mercurial repository that has nested repositories. Using the docs it's very difficult to get what I want.

Comment: What is it that you want that hgweb/hgwebdir doesn't provide?

Comment: It's insanely hard to setup. And I don't have time to fiddle around with Python/CGI. I tried for a few hours and nothing worked.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using [RhodeCode](http://rhodecode.org/) which gives you a very nice Mercurial server. Setting it up was not difficult using the nice documentation that comes with it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [HGInit Tutorial](http://hginit.com/)?  The [Setting Up For a Team section](http://hginit.com/02.html) specifically covers this.  (There's a web server built into hg.)